# What is the error "error: type mismatch;" in scala?

Tags: scala

```
import java.time.LocalDate
object Main extends App{
    val scores: Seq[Score] = Seq(score1, score2, score3, score4)
    println(getDate(scores)(LocalDate.of(2020, 1, 30))("Alice"))
    def getDate(scoreSeq: Seq[Score]): Map[LocalDate, Map[String, Int]] = scores.groupMap(score => score.date)(score=>Map(score.name -> (score.english+score.math+score.science)))
}
```

I would like to implement a function that maps the examination date to a map of student names and the total scores of the three subjects on that date, and if there are multiple scores for the same student on the same date, the function returns the one with the highest total score. However, here is the function

found :scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.time.LocalDate,Seq[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]]]]

"required: Map[java.time.LocalDate,Map[String,Int]]".

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Its like when asked to provide a `Car`, you actually provided a `Cup`. And the compiler is telling you that it wanted a `Car` and not this `Cup`.

Comment: How can I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means what it says: The type of the variable and the type of the value being assigned to the variable don't match. It even tells you what the two types are!

The actual problem is that `groupMap` isn't returning the type you think it should. The values in the resulting `Map` are a `Seq` of `Map`s rather than a single `Map` with all the results.

You can use `groupMapReduce` to convert the `List` to a single `Map` by concatenation the `Map`s using `++`:

```
scores
  .groupMapReduce(_.date)
    (score=>Map(score.name -> (score.english+score.math+score.science)))
    (_ ++ _)
```